# create a superuser and adminuser using django restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have a custom user model and i want to create a superuser from a view right, am currently using django restframework, below is my custom model and serializer with the views.
model.py

```
class CompanyUserManager(UserManager):
    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given username, email and passsword
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The email must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        username = self.model.normalize_username(username)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username: str, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_admin_user(self, username: str, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_admin', True)

        # if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        #     raise ValueError('Super user must have is_staff=True')
        # if extra_fields.get('is_admin') is not True:
        #     raise ValueError('Super user must have is_admin=True')
        # if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is True:
        #     raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=False')
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username: str, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_admin', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Super user must have is_staff=True')
        if extra_fields.get('is_admin') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Super user must have is_admin=True')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True')
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)


# Create your models here.
class CompanyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=150, unique=True, help_text='Required, 150 characters or fewer', error_messages={'unique ': ' a User with this user name is already registered'}, validators=[username_validator])
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=False, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(_('phone'), max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=True, help_text='Designated user can login using this account')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True, help_text='Designated whether this user should be treated as active')
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(_('superuser'), default=False, help_text='Designated user can login using this account')
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(_('admin'), default=False, help_text='Designated user can login using this account')
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(_('email_verified'), default=False,)
    objects = CompanyUserManager()

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD: str = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'phone']

    @property
    def token(self):
        token = jwt.encode({
            'username': self.username,
            'email': self.email,
            'exp': datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=24)},
            settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')
        return token
       
    @property
    def staff(self):
        return self.is_staff

    @property
    def admin(self):
        return self.is_admin

    @property
    def active(self):
        return self.is_active

    @property
    def owner(self):
        return self.is_superuser
```

serializer.py

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    # email = serializers.EmailField()
    # password = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    # password2 = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    # def validate(self, data):
    #     if data['password'] != data['password2']:
    #         raise serializers.ValidationError('Passwords must match')
    #     return data

    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CompanyUser
        fields = ("id", "username", "email", "password", "is_active")
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = CompanyUser(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data["password"])
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, validated_data):
        user = CompanyUser(**validated_data)
        print(validated_data)
        if "password" in validated_data:
            from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

            validated_data["password"] = make_password(validated_data["password"])
        user.set_password(validated_data["password"])
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        return user
```

the create_superuser isnt working, it throws a keyerror password not found

view.py

```
class RegisterAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    """
    A view that allow company owners to create an account
    """
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializers = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializers.is_valid():
            serializers.save()
            # self.serializer_class.create_superuser(serializers.data)
            # serializers.create_superuser(serializers.data)
            return Response(serializers.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializers.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

so this are my codes and i cant create a superuser from the endpoint, i dont want to use the django cli, any help please

Comment: Does it give you 400 error?

Comment: Noo 500 error @DavidLu

Comment: Can you show me the error message?